# MySQL Stored procedure to sanitize a table's data?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So I'm completely new to MySQL Stored procedures, so bear with my ignorance please.

I'm trying to replicate a MSSql script I used to use (that I no longer have), that would create a stored procedure, run that stored procedure against set of known tables/columns, and replace their values with "generic_"+rowid+"text@someplace.com" (using email as an example), then when it was done, remove the stored procedure.

I currently have a php script that does what I need, but it is incredible slow (40k records took almost 14 hours).

Does anybody know of a way to do what I'm trying to do (or point me in the right direction on what I'm trying to do).

For reference, I'm trying to sanitize a Magento 2 database for dev environments. So I'm only caring about customers first name, last name and email address, which are all stored in the same table.

I would like it to do something like:

Original data:

```
ID, FIRST, LAST, Email, Address1, Address2, Postal
------------------------------------------------------
456, Joe, Smith, joe.smith@yahoo.com, 1 haha st, disneyland, K8H 8V3
```

Sanitized to:

```
ID, FIRST, LAST, Email, Address1, Address2, Postal
------------------------------------------------------
456, First_456, Last_456, someone_456@someplace.local, 456 somewhere st, someplace, H0H 0H0
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, or even better, maybe post a sample of something that does the above ? (obviously I'd have to adjust for table and column names).

Comment: What exactly is the question? You want us to write a procedure to do some update statements? And why do you even need that procedure, when a few update statements would suffice? And why would you create and throw away the procedure each time?

Comment: Well, from previous research, I couldn't find a way to get the current rowID and insert that as value into its own row. So I'm guessing that a stored proc would get around this problem, and be able to run this at database speed, not php speed.  The reason to create and destroy the procedure, is because I don't want anybody to accidentally re-run the procedure, and "double" the sanitization process. So single run only, remove the stored proc, it cannot be run again (without re-running the whole script, which requires understanding).

Comment: `so bare with my ignorance please` I'm keeping my clothes on, thanks

Comment: as @fancyPants said i would reccomend you only to make simple update script with possibility to mark somewhere that you have treated that row so you will not do reupdate if you relaunch that.

Comment: Ok, I'm less worried about removing the stored proc afterwards, but need help with the stored proc itself, on how to replace a table of content, row by row, including each row's own RowID.

Comment: Could you post a 10-second snippet of your MySQL General Log to pastebin.com so we can 'see' what is going on during this process?  Of course, after we see the queries, we will want A) SHOW CREATE TABLE (for tables involved); and B) SHOW INDEX FROM (each table involved); so we can understand your indexes and cardinality of each column indexed.